# Look up values from another Excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with a list of products.
It has headings such as Product, size, order number, color etc
The sheet is created once a week and the information varies from week to week
For example: Product X might appear three times with three different order numbers one week, might only show once another week but not be present in the following week etc etc. Also the order of the products in the list could be different each week.

Example:

| Product | Size | Order # | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 22 | 12Q12 | Blue |
| A | 22 | 23SD2 | Blue |
| A | 22 | 11CL9 | Blue |
| C | 21 | 12WK3 | Red |
| D | 33 | 24SH2 | Green |
| D | 33 | 33AN7 | Green |
| D | 33 | 33AN7 | Green |
| E | 22 | 37NB5 | Red |

On another worksheet I have a list of all products and their corresponding price.

| Product | Price |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2$ |
| B | 5$ |
| C | 6$ |
| D | 1$ |
| E | 3$ |

I wish to add the price for each item in a new column on the first sheet taken from the price list.
For example wherever product A shows, the corresponding price will show in another column.

I feel like V-lookup is what I want but not sure how to implement it

Any help appreciated!

I feel like V-lookup is what I want but not sure how to implement it. I tried that but couldn't get it to carry over from the other sheet.

Comment: If sheets are named as Sheet1, Sheet2, apply formula `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)` on Sheet1 cell E2. Then fill formula through all cells in column E.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the formulas that will do it. See the picture for reference:

```
=VLOOKUP(B3,$J$3:$K$7,2,0)

=XLOOKUP(B3:B10,J3:J7,K3:K7)
```

[image: Picture Reference]